# What is the special meaning of "+" in URLs?

Tags: urlencode

"+" is a reserved character in URLs and encodes to "%2B".

**What is its special meaning?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the URL-encoded value of space. For example, search for "url encoding" (without the quotes) in Google, and then look at the URL. It will include

```
q=url+encoding
```

Note the plus where the space was.

Comment: Of course. I've used "+" like that before, I just had assumed that there was some hidden technical usage :)

Answer (score 7):

Space (which can also be represented as `%20`, but `+` is more readable).

Answer (score 1):

hiii...
In ISO-Latin charecter set + is a charecter which, can be used for concatenation or addition.
But when we use it in url it represents space.
Thus it has diffrent meaning in url.
It has diffrent meaning in url because ,it is reserved charecter in url , used for space.

Answer (score 0):

It's a space.  Need 15 characters...